# Exclude a field from tastypie api

Tags: django, tastypie

I need to exclude a field on the basis of the value of some other field. The relationship between them is as follows.

```
class Moo: 
   ...

class Too:
        moo = models.ForeignKey(Moo, related_name='moo_too')

        ...

class PooToo:
       moo = models.ForeignKey(Moo) 
       stature = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(..)
       ...

class PooMooResource(ModelResource):

    moo = ToOneField(StandAloneMooResource, 'moo', full=True)
    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        queryset = PooMoo.objects.select_related('moo').all()

class StandAloneMooResource(ModelResource):

    too = ToManyField(TooResource,...)
    class Meta:
            queryset = Moo.objects.all()
```

Now I want to expose the `too` field in the API only when `stature==0`, otherwise not. I can use `use_in` for this, but the problem is I do not have the value of `stature` in `StandAloneMooResource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class StandAloneMooResource(ModelResource):

    too = ToManyField(TooResource,...)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Moo.objects.all()

    def dehydrate_too(self, bundle):
        # if this method is run while dehdyrating PooMooResource.moo,
        # related_obj should be the related PooMoo
        if bundle.related_obj and bundle.related_obj.stature != 0:
            return None
        return bundle.data['too']
```

Unfortunately the 'too' key will still be there, and tastypie will still go through the effort of retrieving the tutorials from the DB.

This might be better:

```
def foo(bundle):
    if bundle.related_obj and bundle.related_obj.stature != 0:
        return None
    return bundle.obj.tutorials.all()

class StandAloneMooResource(ModelResource):

    too = ToManyField(TooResource, attribute=foo)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Moo.objects.all()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # to remove the 'tutorials' key
        if 'too' in bundle.data and not bundle.data['too']:
            del bundle.data['too']
        return bundle
```

If `bundle.related_obj` isn't working:

```
def foo(bundle):
    poomoo = None
    try:
        # assumes PooMoo.user a relation to User
        poomoo = PooMoo.objects.filter(moo=bundle.obj, user=bundle.request.user)[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    if poomoo and poomoo.stature != 0:
        return None
    return bundle.obj.too.all()
```

Comment: Hey Seán Hayes, Many thanks for the help. In the second option you suggested `bundle.related_obj` is always `None`.

Comment: Shoot. Looks like `bundle.related_obj` only gets set during hydration. I'll put in a ticket.

In the meantime, you could always try something like this (check updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
class StandAloneMooResource(ModelResource):

    tutorials = ToManyField(TutorialResource,...)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Moo.objects.filter(Q(pootoo__isnull = False, pootoo__status=0) | Q(pootoo__isnull=True))
```

You can check http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html

Comment: I've updated the code again to show mission if playermission is already null and to show mission if it has not a playermission. "playermission" can be changed using related_name attribute in model class

Comment: I want to exclude only the tutorial field when status=0. Your solution will only fetch mission data with playermission status =0 + PlayerMission model is not a part of Mission model so above code is not applicable.

Comment: playermission keyword is a reverse relation. you can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward.

Comment: Yes it will return it when status = 0 and this is what I understood from "only when status==0"